# magento upgrade not listing latest available upgrade in connect manager

Tags: magento, upgrade, magento-1.12

I want to upgrade my magento version.

I am using **Magento Enterprise editon 1.12**

When I goto connect manager and use "Check for upgrade". No upgrade is listed. But **Magento 1.14 is latest version and it is not listed**.

Any reason on why didn't the available is not listed?

For community edition we can upgrade manually by downloading the latest files and inserting  our custom modules in that.

But in Enterprise Edition is there any way to do like that? Because Enterprise Edition is not open source

The same question is posted [in this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99166/magento-upgrade-not-listing-latest-available-upgrade-in-connect-manager) . Since I am not getting any response, posting the same here

Answer (score 1):

Magento Enterprise is the PAID version. You will need to login to the Magento Account to be able to download the latest version.

In case, of Magento Community, it is free hence it can be upgraded via Magento Connect Manager.

Use the following steps:

- Go to www.magento.com
- In the top horizontal navigation bar, click My
  Account. Log in with your Magento user name and password.
- In the left navigation bar, click Downloads.
- In the right pane, click Magento Enterprise Edition > Release for the software or Sample Data for the optional sample data.
- Follow the instructions on your screen to complete the Magento EE download.
- Transfer the installation archive to your development system.

Find the information here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing.html#get

Hope this helps.